# How to set number of <td> tag dynamically where number of <td> tag is fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table looks like below:

```
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor=#0D9381>
<th rowspan=2><center>Characteristics</center></th>
<th rowspan=2><center>Spec.</center></th>
<th colspan=<%=gcaqa.getX2() %>><center>Observed<br>Value</center></th>
<th rowspan=2><center>Date of<br>Analysis</center></th>
</tr>
<%
if(vaqm!=null && vaqm.size()>0){
    for(class_div h11:vaqm){
%>
<tr bgcolor=#02321D>
<td><center><%=h11.getCharacteristics() %></center></td>
<td><center><%=h11.getSpec() %></center></td>
<td><center><%=h11.getObservedValue1() %></center></td>
<td><center><%=h11.getObservedValue2() %></center></td>
<td><center><%=h11.getObservedValue3() %></center></td>
<td><center><%=h11.getDateofAnalysis() %></center></td>
</tr>
<%
    }
}
%>
</table>
```

But here I want to show only `<%=gcaqa.getX2() %>` number of Observed Value out of `<%=h11.getObservedValue1() %>`, `<%=h11.getObservedValue2() %>` and `<%=h11.getObservedValue3() %>`
that is out of 3rd, 4th and 5th td tag I want to display only `<%=gcaqa.getX2() %>` number of td tag.

I made it sure that number of observed value is less than or equals to `<%=gcaqa.getX2() %>`.

Please someone give any clue. Because there is no clue in the internet. In my case `<%=gcaqa.getX2() %>` is 2. So, to be very clear. I want to show only two td tag containing observed value out of 3.

Comment: What's all of this stuff `<%=`? Add a tag to your question for that.

Comment: @wazz Inside these <%= > are the data coming from database